# How to build an app automated with flutter

Tags: flutter, automation

Is it possible to make the whole flutter app will be build on a just click of a button?
Providing launcher icon, jks key, app version code, providing splash screen image with all that.

How can i build that script?
Or is there any tool for that?

Comment: how about git-action just for building

Comment: you can look into https://pub.dev/packages/mason_cli

Comment: @YeasinSheikh can github action be called through api?